# Why need npm in backbone if backbone js is included in script

Tags: backbone.js

Hello I am new in backbone. I have following question.

If we just include backbone js and underscore js on html page, still we can use backbone features. Then what is need to install backbone by npm? If it is necessary then please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install backbone by npm if you are ok with staying with specific version of backbone and dependencies and updating them manually if you need a version update. Considering backbone is not under active development, this isn't  a bad option, especially for small or pet projects. Having a build setup with tools like NPM, Bower etc lets you resolve dependencies and update all libraries easily in case of bigger projects

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there any way to hide implementation of mvc? Because anyone can see all stuff by viewing page source.